# What is "dismal"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've struggled with this word for about 2 years (no joke). Every time I see it, I look it up, kind of understand what it means in that context, and then gleefully forget.

Please help me understand the origin and meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best way to describe dismal is as the opposite of cheerful. A grey rainy day is dismal, whereas a bright sunny day is cheerful.

It can also mean poor quality: 'Football Team United's performance was dismal!'

It comes from the Latin *dies mali* 'evil days', via French.